# bootstrap column layout in different size containers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, multiple-columns, responsive

Lets say that I've created some components that use the bootstrap columns for layout.  Those components render well as long as I've set them inside a screen-wide container.  ie:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6"/><div class="col-lg-6"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

However, lets say I now want to display this same component into a smaller space.  ie: lets say its moving from the Main column, into a side column.

How do I get the columns to stack vs appearing side by side.  My use of "col-lg" only applies to the screensize.  Instead, I want to get these columns to react to their container size.

Answer (score 0):

for smaller screen you can use these clases: col-xs-{number}, col-sm-{number}, col-md-{number}

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"/>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"/>
```

Comment: Issue is not smaller screen size.  Lets say in the same screen size, I move the component from a wider region into a narrower region.  Currently, it won't reflow because the layout is based on screen size, instead of container size.